# Converting big.Int to [2]int64, vice-versa and two's complement

Tags: go, bigint

I am trying to convert Go big.Int, which will represent a 128-bit integer to [2]int64. The idea is to be able to match Rust's i128::to_le_bytes(), which encodes 128-bit signed integer into little-endian byte order. The example matches Rust's `i128::to_le_bytes()`. Whenever I try to convert it back to big.Int, I do not get the same value. Is there any bit lost when doing the initial right shift? Thanks.

```golang
package main
 
import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)
 
func main() {
    initial := new(big.Int)
    initial.SetString("-42", 10)
 
    value, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("-42", 10)
 
    var result [2]int64
 
    result[0] = value.Int64()
    result[1] = value.Rsh(value, 64).Int64()
 
    leRepresentation := make([]byte, 16)
 
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(leRepresentation[:8], uint64(result[0]))
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(leRepresentation[8:], uint64(result[1]))
 
    fmt.Println(leRepresentation)
 
    fmt.Println(result)
 
    reverse := big.NewInt(result[1])
    reverse.Lsh(reverse, 64)
    reverse.Add(reverse, big.NewInt(result[0]))
 
    fmt.Println(reverse.String())
 
    fmt.Println(initial.String() == reverse.String())
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this conversion? Do you just want a way to store the `BigInt` into a 128 bit container, or do you expect `result[0]` and `result[1]` to have some meaning?

Comment: The point of this conversion is to encode the number in little-endian format, similar to Rust's `i128::to_le_bytes`. Having a `leRepresentation := make([]byte,16)` and encoding them one after another like `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(leRepresentation[:8], uint64(result[0])`, `binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(leRepresentation[8:], uint64(result[1])` matches Rust's `i128::to_le_bytes()`. Having operations like addition, subtraction with the number in Go would be easier by converting it back to big.Int and do them.

Comment: What do you want to do with the number once you put it in this format?

Comment: Having the number encoded will allow me to pass it to a Rust application, which will be able to decode it natively. The idea is to be able to pass it between different applications written in Go/Rust and be able to do different operations like addition/subtraction, etc. with the actual number.

Comment: Unfortunately, the underlying format of `big.Int` is unsigned and big endian. Btw, looks like rust has a `from_be_bytes`. The most direct path I see is passing big-endian bytes and sign with `Int.Bytes` and `Int.Sign`, then decoding in rust with `from_be_bytes` and multiplying by the sign value.

Comment: Since Rust is able to encode and decode it without an additional byte for the sign, for example: `-1` is little-endian encoded into `0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`, I do not understand why in Go this would not be possible. Would it be possible recreate the correct `big.Int` based on the `[2]int64`, given that I know the bytes represent a 128-bit signed integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here:

`value` cannot be represented by an `int64`, so the result of `value.Int64()` is undefined.

Your lower bits are not taking into account the signed result of `Int64`, so you could be adding a negative number to the result. You need to use a `uint64` (or at at least convert it before adding it to the `big.Int`).

You are mutating `value` in the `Rsh` method, so the comparison at the end would fail even if the value were recreated correctly. Create a new `big.Int` to store the original value if you want to compare it.

If you want a raw data representation for the `big.Int` with exactly 128bits, you can use the [`FillBytes`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.FillBytes) method. We can take that big-endian data and build the 2 64bit values like so:

```
b := make([]byte, 16)
value.FillBytes(b)  

var result [2]uint64
result[0] = binary.BigEndian.Uint64(b[:8])
result[1] = binary.BigEndian.Uint64(b[8:])
```

Now that the byte order is fixed, add the sign bit to the result. In order to make this work like an `int128` however, we need to use two's compliment to set the sign

```
const sign = uint64(1 << 63)
if value.Sign() < 0 {
    // convert the unsigned value to two's compliment
    result[0] = ^result[0]
    result[1] = ^result[1]

    result[1]++
    // check for carry
    if result[1] == 0 {
        result[0]++
    }
}
```

To create a new `big.Int`, reverse the entire process:

```
neg := uint128[0]&sign != 0
if neg {
    // reverse the two's compliment
    if uint128[1] == 0 {
        uint128[0]--
    }
    uint128[1]--

    uint128[0] = ^uint128[0]
    uint128[1] = ^uint128[1]
}

b := make([]byte, 16)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(b[:8], uint128[0])
binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(b[8:], uint128[1])

result := new(big.Int).SetBytes(b)
if neg {
    result.Neg(result)
}
```

An example testing a number of key values: https://go.dev/play/p/E1E-5CilFlr

Because the output is written as an unsigned value, if it's possible to start with values > MaxInt128, you should also add a check to make sure you're not overflowing the signed value. Storing these as `[2]int64` is a lot messier because we need uint64 values for the bitwise operations, and we need to make sure the `int64` values aren't rolled over via their own two's compliment. In that case it's easier to convert the `[2]int64` to and from `[2]uint64` around the given functions.

Comment: Thank you for the fixes. Unfortunately, this does not apply for negative numbers, e.g. -170141183460469231731687303715884105728, -42.

Comment: If we exclude the errors from the initial code sample, would it be possible to recreate the big.Int from a [2]int64?

Comment: @plenio:  How _exactly_ do you expect these to be encoded? Simply saying "represent a 128-bit integer a [2]int64" is ambiguous.

Comment: in little-endian format, similar to how they are encoded in Rust, specifically i128.

Comment: I have updated the initial post question.

Comment: @plenio: I turned the example into a 128bit two's compliment, and added a few tests since this has expanded to more than just "serializing the value in [2]uint64"

Comment: I am extremely grateful for you help. Thanks!